# Nginx Redirect when Page size is greater than a certain number

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

looking for some help with location redirect on our nginx config.

I've tried so many permutations that I just cant get to work.

I want to return a error code when a request comes in with a page=4000 and above

http://www.example.co.uk/kung/foo/results?language=en&page=54976&sort=publicationDateDesc

I've tried so many permutations that I dare not list them all